# Uncaught TypeError with Stripe Buy Button in React: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'payload')'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate the Stripe Buy Button into my React application, but I'm encountering an `Uncaught TypeError` when the page is reloaded. The integration seems to work initially when I save my React component, but the error occurs on page reload. I have followed the Stripe integration guidelines, but I am still facing this issue. Here is how I have set it up:

**index.html:**

```html
    <head>
      <!-- Paste the script snippet in the head of your app's index.html -->
      <script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js"></script>
    </head>
```

**BuyButtonComponent.js:**

```js
    import * as React from 'react';
    
    function BuyButtonComponent() {
      // Paste the stripe-buy-button snippet in your React component
      return (
        <stripe-buy-button
          buy-button-id="..."
          publishable-key="..."
        >
        </stripe-buy-button>
      );
    }
    
    export default BuyButtonComponent;
```

**Error:**

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'payload')
        at HTMLElement.value (buy-button.js:1:6977)
    value @ buy-button.js:1
```

Initial page reload upon saving my React script doesn't produce any error and the button works as expected. This error seems to occur specifically on reloading the page afterwards. I'm not able to modify the buy-button.js script since it's an external resource loaded from Stripe.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or does anyone know why this might be happening? Any suggestions on how to resolve or debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to use the button, or is the error affecting the functionality?

Comment: I can use the button, it's just that the error is displaying all across the screen in development mode, so I was worried it would also display that in production. If it's just a console error I could live with it, right?

Comment: As long as everything works as expected you can ignore the error.